# excel vba - create a collection with entries out of an array

Tags: vba, excel

is there a way to create collections with the entries of an array? 
i have an array with three entries:

```
dim components(1 to 3)
components(1) = "A"
components(2) = "B"
components(3) = "C"
```

now i want to iterate through the array and create for each component a collection:

```
for each c in components
    dim c as new collection
next
```

but this throws an error.

Thank you

Comment: What did you mean by `dim c as new collection` in for each loop?

Comment: i want to create a new collection with the name of the entry in the array. i want to create the collections ( A, B and C)

Comment: if foreach loop, `c` is `component`, you are modifying already defined `c`! try renaming your variable to something like this: `dim col as new collection`

Comment: but then, i´m creating just one collection. i want to create three collections with the names of the array

Comment: So basically you want to create a variable (object) within a loop, if I'm correct. I'm pretty sure, this does not work, unfortunately. Maybe consider just looping through the array and work with the values at current position.

Comment: ^^ As said above. Also, it is worth including the error description and indicating the line on which it occurs when asking for debugging help.

Comment: ok, thank you very much! i have to rethink my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple collections, create a collection of collections. You can't squash multiple collections into the variable "c".

`for each c in components
    *add new subcollection to a main collection*
next`